# how make two carets/hats/circumflexes ^^ unspecial

Tags: characters, catcodes

I want to make ^ unspecial in a command definition, i. e. “^” in the input should give the “^” character in the output. Setting the catcode to 11 or 12 works—but not for “^^”. Instead LaTeX replaces “^^!” by “a” and “^^h” by “(”. What’s happening here and what can I do against that?

Hints:

- The ASCII codes of !, a; h, ( are 0x21, 0x61; 0x28, 0x68. The same problem for other characters: ^^ vanishes and 0x40 is added to *or* subtracted from the next character. My personal WTF moment.
- The problem is the same for LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\func}[1]{{%
    \catcode94=12\relax%^
    \catcode95=12\relax%_
    \scantokens{#1}%
}}

\begin{document}
OK:\func{_!_h}

OK:\func{^!^h}

OK:\func{__!__h}

NOT OK:\func{^^!^^h}

\catcode94=12\relax
\catcode95=12\relax
OK:__!__h

OK:^^!^^h
\end{document}
```

Sorry for that not-minimal code example; I wanted to show that __ (two _) doesn’t have that problem and that the problem occurs only when I try that function definition.

Comment: if you make `^` catcode 12 then `^` will act as a normal character but you need to do it before you scan the argument, as is usual with tex macros and catcode changes

Comment: About your "WTF moment", see _The TeXBook_, Appendix C: Character Codes. Quote: "Here `^^` doesn't necessarily mean two circumflex characters; it means two identical characters whose current `\catcode` is 7. In such cases TeX simply adds or subtracts _'100_ [64 in decimal] from the internal code of the character that immediately follows. For example, `*` can also be typed as `^^j`; `j` can also be typed as `^^*`." This is the way Knuth implemented so that users can type all the 128 ASCII characters, not just the visible (or available in your keybord) range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You need to change the catcode before you scan the argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\func}{\bgroup%
    \catcode94=12\relax%^
    \catcode95=12\relax%_
    \xfunc}
\newcommand\xfunc[1]{\scantokens{#1}\egroup}

\begin{document}
OK:\func{_!_h}

OK:\func{^!^h}

OK:\func{__!__h}

NOT OK:\func{^^!^^h}

\catcode94=12\relax
\catcode95=12\relax
OK:__!__h

OK:^^!^^h
\end{document}
```

The difference between `_` and `^` is that `__!` still makes three tokens so you can "correct" the tokens to have catcode12 even after the argument has been parsed by using `\scantokens` but as `^^!` just parses as a single token, `\scantokens` can not be used to get three catcode 12 tokens.